# How can I print an Object of a Vector when this last is into a Main-Vector?

Tags: java, oop, vector

How can I print a Vector that is into a Vector (main).
I made a program that contains a vector of stacks (java.util), inside the package I have two classes:
-Stack, -mainProgram;
The Stack class will create the object though a Vector (java.util) with the following methods: pop,push,peek,isEmpty,search,print. I did everything but I don't know how to print the stack  contained in the Vector (main)  with Its elements, where I should be able to add,remove,search and print the stacks.

Example of what I mean:

The print of the stacks that I wanna print should be like this -->

---


Stack 1:
 10
 20
 30
 40 
50 
60

---

Stack 2:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

---

Stack 3:
 100
 110
 120
 130

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Vector anymore since it has become a legacy class years ago.

If you need to implement a Stack with a data structure of the Collections framework, then an [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is your best choice.

> This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack

However, if using a Vector is a constraint, you can simply print your elements with two nested fors. I've assumed that your innermost Vector contains Strings.

```
public void print(Vector<Vector<String>> vet){
        int i = 0;
        for (Vector<String> v : vet) {
            System.out.printf("Stack %d:%n", ++i);
            for (String s : v) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

The implementation with an ArrayDeque would be exactly the same

```
public void print(ArrayDeque<ArrayDeque<String>> vet){
        int i = 0;
        for (ArrayDeque<String> v : vet) {
            System.out.printf("Stack %d:%n", ++i);
            for (String s : v) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I'm an high school student that's why I'm still using Vector. I don't know what exactly ArrayDeque is, I will inquire about it. 
Anyway, could you explain to me better the functioning of those two "for"?